# I created Angular project and do it live but when i live the page is blank on when i use www

Tags: angular, angular16

I created Angular project and do it live but when i use "https//" then the page is apear but i use "www." the page is blank but the favicon and the web title is appear

when deploy the project I use this:-
`ng build --configuration production --base-href "https://example.com"`

I want to open when some one type [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and also on https://example.com

Comment: Where and how did you deploy the application? Please, attach some relevant code.

Comment: The base href should be also `/`. it's used, e.g. if you want an url like `www.example.com/myapp`, and in this case you use as href **only** `/myapp`

Comment: I use in base url "/myapp" but the page is blank only come the web title. this is the link --> http://bempl.in/demo/aumen/